# Which hard drive corresponds to ata1.00 and ata12.00?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

I  have an Ubuntu installation which has a lot of hard drives. Two of these drives have hiccups and SMART is reporting errors. However, I cannot figure out how to determine which drive is ata1.00 and which is ata12.00. Is it possible to retrieve their serial numbers, as this would be easiest way to find the correct drives?

Comment: This answer may help you out: [Mapping ata device number to logical device name](http://superuser.com/a/617193/23585). Sorry that I am so late to the party.

Comment: A duplicate on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/244944/linux-ata-errors-translating-to-a-device-name

Answer (score 6):

`ls -l /sys/class/ata_port/` should show the link to PCI id. Then `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/` would tell you what /dev/* that that is assigned to.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` and find the `sd*` device that corresponds. Then look at `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` for the model and serial number that corresponds to that `sd*` device.

You may find this helpful:

```
sudo lshw -class disk -short
```

(or try it without the `-short` but pipe it into `less`).

Comment: Ok, using lshw, I get: /0/100/1c.1/0/0  /dev/sda   disk       1TB WDC WD10EADS-00M. Is there any information about how mapping between /0/100/1c.1/0/0 with ata1.00?

Comment: @user70520: What do the `ls ... /dev/disk` commands I posted tell you?

Comment: @user70520: What is it that's reporting the drive as "ata1.00"? Try this to get a list of serial numbers (and other information) about all your drives: `for d in /dev/sd?; do sudo smartctl -i $d; done | less`.

Comment: I get SMART error in dmesg, thus I have to identify corect drives to replace: [2293721.950045] ata12.00: status: { DRDY }
[2293721.950051] ata12: hard resetting link

Comment: I need to figure out which drive ata12.00 is. If I get either /dev/sdX or serial, I can figure out which drive I need to replace.

Answer (score 2):

```
lshw -C disk
```

will get you drives, their product ids, and mount points.

```
*-disk:0                
       description: ATA Disk
       product: XXXX
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: JC4B
       serial: XXXYYY
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=0006ded4
```

You can then find their most recent mount info in /var/log/syslog, with something like
(e.g. looking for disk /dev/sda)

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep 'sda' -A 5 -B 5
```

for other info, you can also try

```
blkid
```

or

```
mount
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the output of `ll /sys/block` which shall give you something similar to

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0 Jul  9 14:55 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 dm-0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/dm-0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop1 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop1/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop2 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop2/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop3 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop3/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop4 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop4/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop5 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop5/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop6 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop6/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 loop7 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop7/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 md0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/md0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 nvme0n1 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 nvme1n1 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:01.0/0000:23:00.0/nvme/nvme1/nvme1n1/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 nvme2n1 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:2d:00.0/nvme/nvme2/nvme2n1/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:0a.0/0000:2c:00.0/ata6/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sda/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Aug  8 09:00 sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:20:00.0/0000:21:09.0/0000:2b:00.0/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sdb/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the device name but know the bus number of an IDE harddrive, and want to find out the serial number, you can do:

```
cat /sys/bus/ide/devices/0.0/serial
```

Where "0.0" is the bus number.

Comment: I do not have ide, but sata which seems to map to scsi on Ubuntu Lucid: root@na:/sys/bus/scsi/devices# ls
0:0:0:0   11:0:0:0  15:0:0:0  6:0:0:0  host0  host10  host12  host14  host16  host2  host4  host6  host8  target0:0:0   target11:0:0  target15:0:0  target6:0:0
10:0:0:0  14:0:0:0  3:0:0:0   7:0:0:0  host1  host11  host13  host15  host17  host3  host5  host7  host9  target10:0:0  target14:0:0  target3:0:0   target7:0:0. I am do not seem to be able to find the missing link.

Comment: I suspect you're missing 'lsscsi' which will output something like :
    [0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST3500630AS      3.AA  /dev/sda
    [1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD5000AAKS-0 05.0  /dev/sdb
    [6:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-S202H  SB00  /dev/sr0

Where ATA.1 is /dev/sdb and ATA.0 would be /dev/sda.

Answer (score 0):

You want `hdparm -i /dev/whatever`.

Comment: root@na# hdparm -i /dev/sdb 

/dev/sdb:

 Model=WDC, FwRev=80.00A80, SerialNo=WD-WCAVY1924737
 Config={ HardSect NotMFM HdSw>15uSec SpinMotCtl Fixed DTR>5Mbs FmtGapReq }
 RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=50
 BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=0kB, MaxMultSect=16, MultSect=16
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=3907029168
 IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
[snip]
 Drive conforms to: Unspecified:  ATA/ATAPI-1,2,3,4,5,6,7


I am still not able to see how I can determine which drive (sdX) corresponds to ata1.00

Comment: @user70520: You wanted the serial number; there it is: “SerialNo=WD-WCAVY1924737”.

Comment: I wanted the serial number, yes. but I want the serail number of harddrive which corresponds to ata1.00. That is my main problem, pfinding the link between ata1.00 and /dev/sdX

Comment: @user70520: Oh, you don't have the device name?  Right - see separate answer.